# Problems with colour conversion

Tags: imageresizer

I see extrem colour changes on tif files converted to jpg/png.

Try this:
http://files2.hanser.de/Files/Article/ARTK_CT1_9783446247246_0001.tif?scale=both&format=jpg&decoder=freeimage&quality=80&height=2000

for a the wrong Colour, it appears green while the tiff itself is tourquise.
You can download the original tif from the same address.

I tried with all kinds of Settings, ignoreicc, with and without freeimage Decoder, jpg vs. png, etc. - no Change of appearance.

What to do ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I looked into your situation and found several CMYK related bugs in old patch notes for the freeimage decoder. The TIF you are providing has a CMYK color profile. They have since been fixed. Removing the freeimage decode tag produced the desired result. 
 Is your imageresizer core and freeimage plugin up to date?

http://files2.hanser.de/Files/Article/ARTK_CT1_9783446247246_0001.tif?scale=both&format=jpg&quality=80&height=2000

Produces

[A resulting JPG with the correct colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFSww.png)

Comment: Oops, send too soon.
Under an OEM licence I use the latest release provided which does not need licence keys installed, downloaded in dec 2015.
Removing the freeimage decoder does not really solve the probem, just reduces the differences in color. Please see [sample](http://www.onixtools.de/downloads/tiff_colors.png) where the original tiff showed in Windows Picture preview is put next to the jpg created from it in the browser.
Resizer debug and Version info is [here](http://files2.hanser.de/resizer.debug.ashx)

Comment: PS I am using Version 4.0.4.934 of the libraries

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce color shift when converting CMYK to RGB if your server's display profile is set to sRGB. 
.NET's System.Drawing is designed exclusively for display purposes, and targets your server's current ICC profile, which is not always sRGB.

We hope (assuming sufficient funding), to eliminate both FreeImage and System.Drawing in a future version of ImageResizer, which will give us the control required to have perfectly accurate colorspace conversions. 
https://github.com/imazen/imageflow

Comment: Nathanael, this issue is still not solved. Removing freeimage Decoder and builder does reduce the difference but not solve them finally. You recommended changing the Servers ICC Default Profile. Where would I do that? I have done some Research but couldn't find anything about it. Or else, when would you have a production Version available (v5?) which is able to produce correct colours even from tifs with embedded Color profiles? Thanks.

Comment: I managed to provide almost true colors by removing freeimage as builder and decoder PLUS using the latest ImageResizer.dll with version ID 4.0.5.942. However, I only got the testversion which creates the red dot in the lower right corner.

As I have an OEM Licence I would like to have the licence free dlls to distribute with my product in this newest version. The download I received right after buying the licence is version 4.0.4.934 from the archive Resizer4-0-4-full-Oct-25-2015-drm-free.zip.

Where can I download Resizer4-0-5-full-???-??-2017-drm-free.zip ?

Comment: Your order confirmation e-mail includes a link that contains a regularly updated list of releases in DRM-free format.